# Checking value in textbox against an array script not working

Tags: javascript

I have a script that I am checking values from textbox against an array, the array are all values from a drop down list. Cant seem to get it to work. Thanks.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

    function chkName() {

        var ddlArray = new Array();
        var ddl = document.getElementById('DropDownList1');
        for (i = 0; i < ddl.options.length; i++) {
            ddlArray[i] = ddl.options[i].value;
        }



        var str = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;
        str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ""); // strip leading and trailing spaces
        str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function (w) {
            return w.toUpperCase()
        }); // reformat to lower-case with initial capital

        var match = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < ddlArray.length; i++) {
            if (str == ddlArray[i]) {
                match = true;
            }
        }

        if (match) {
            alert("The name " + str + " does  match our list!");
            document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = "";
            return false;
        } else {

            return true;

        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where did "v" come from?

Comment: And you can leave the loop like this `match = true;
break;`

Comment: Nitpick Doing `document.getElementById("TextBox1")` over and over again in the same function is bad. Store it in a variable and reference it. Also most modern day browsers support indexOf on arrays.

Comment: try to debug your code by yourself. `console.log([str, ddlArray[i]]);`

Comment: Instead of "new Array()", use "[ ]". And inside of your if statement to check for a match, you can use "break;" after the "match = true;" line. (these won't fix anything, just improve whatever)

Comment: And what is the problem? Are you getting any errors or are you just not getting a match when it's supposed to?

Comment: @user406151 Just curious - are you using .NET or plain html ? Because 'DropDownList1' and 'TextBox1' look like default ids in .net for a textbox or ddl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function chkName() {
    "use strict";
    var ddlArray = [],
        ddl = document.getElementById('DropDownList1'),
        str = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value,
        match = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < ddl.options.length; i++) {
        ddlArray[i] = ddl.options[i].value;
    }

    str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
    str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function( w ) {
        return w.toUpperCase();
    });

    for (i = 0; i < ddlArray.length; i++) {
        if ( str === ddlArray[i] ) {
            alert("The name " + str + " does  match our list!");
            document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = "";
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```